# How do I turn an array of column names into a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of data that represents choices from a large collection, and a classification.  Something like:

```
pizzas = [
['ham','cheese','pineapple'],
['bacon','feta','cheese'],
['mushrooms','feta','ham],
...
]
```

I want to turn this into a data frame with one column for each topping type, with one row for each pizza.  Something like

```
ham  cheese ...  feta
1      1          0
0      1          1
0      0          1
 ...
```

(Obviously there will be a lot more columns and rows, but you get the general idea.)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try first create `DataFrame` from constructor, then use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd

pizzas = [
['ham','cheese','pineapple'],
['bacon','feta','cheese'],
['mushrooms','feta','ham']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(pizzas)
print df
           0       1          2
0        ham  cheese  pineapple
1      bacon    feta     cheese
2  mushrooms    feta        ham

df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='')
print df
   bacon  ham  mushrooms  cheese  feta  cheese  ham  pineapple
0      0    1          0       1     0       0    0          1
1      1    0          0       0     1       1    0          0
2      0    0          1       0     1       0    1          0

print df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
   bacon  cheese  feta  ham  mushrooms  pineapple
0      0       1     0    1          0          1
1      1       1     1    0          0          0
2      0       0     1    1          1          0
```